# Formatting string in XML format and remove invalid attribute characters

Tags: c#, xml, string, xmlwriter, xmlnode

I've a string say `"<Node a="<b>">"`. I need to escape only the data and parse this string as a node in XMLWriter. Hence how to escape only the attribute value "<" and note the XML structure's "<".

Comment: Something like `<Node a="&lt;b&gt;">`?

Comment: Doesn't that happen automatically? If you use the `InnerText` or `Value` Property it gets escaped automatically. If you got that data from someone else, tell them their data is malformed and unusable

Comment: @codran yes I need to make something like that for a string.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I'm not accessing that from XMLNode but instead its a string

Answer (score 2):

```
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("Node");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("a", "<b>");
}
```

Output `<Node a="&lt;b&gt;" />`

---

Firstly you should parse the string. Since this is not valid xml, you can't use an xml parser. You can try HtmlAgilityPack. Then you can write the values with xml writer.

```
string s = "<Node a=\"<b>\">";

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(s);

var node = doc.DocumentNode.FirstChild;
var attr = node.Attributes[0];

using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement(node.Name);
    writer.WriteAttributeString(attr.Name, attr.Value);
}
```

Comment: But I don't know the element name and it itself is in string form. For Ex. string is <Node a=<b>>

Comment: I think this will work, but in case of multiple attributes, we'll have to alter the logic.