# Replace Double Quotes Within Attributes only in XML : C#

Tags: c#, regex, xml, string, escaping

I've this string which will be part of an XML/XML Node:

```
string a = "<Node a=\"a\"[\"\"/>";
```

I need only the attribute quotes to be escaped so that it becomes

```
a= "Node a=\"a&qout;[&qout;\"/>";
```

I'm using C#, .NET 2.0.

Comment: I found this post helpful but couldn't relate to my solution in C# (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744460/java-removing-the-double-quotes-in-xml-attributes)

Comment: string a = "<Node a="a"[""/>" doesn't compile, btw. This does, however string a = "<Node a=\"a\"[\"\"/>"; or this string a = @"<Node a=""a""[""""/>";

Comment: @KSib thanks, I've updated the question. what I need to escape is not the string double quote escape but instead XML double quote escape for attributes.

Comment: You're also going to have a hard time validating this as it isn't valid XML to begin with. I assume this is just a test case and you actually want to do this to a larger XML document?

Comment: @KSib I've just given part of the XML for example to make the question simple. Just assume this as a node.

Comment: Please consider following advice given to you in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36979441/formatting-string-in-xml-format-and-remove-invalid-attribute-characters) and use XML APIs to read/write XML. Or stop calling random text "XML" just because it contains `<` and `>`.

Comment: Question has been answered. Thanks. Please upvote the question if you think it is valid and needs reach.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm not calling random text XML. Whatever string I'm passing is part of XML, which I write into an XML file. Thank you.

Comment: When you say `I've this XML string:` it would be more accurate and helpful to say `I've this non-XML string:`. Because whatever it might be, it's not XML and that's precisely why you need to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you found was correct, it just had to be adapted to C#.

Here is the conversion :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace RegEx
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = "<Node a=\"a\"[\"\" b=\"b\"[\"\"/>   <Node2 a=\"a\"[\"\" b=\"b\"[\"\"/>";
            string regEx = "(\\s+[\\w:.-]+\\s*=\\s*\")(([^\"]*)((\")((?!\\s+[\\w:.-]+\\s*=\\s*\"|\\s*(?:/?|\\?)>))[^\"]*)*)\"";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            int currentPos = 0;
            foreach(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(text, regEx)) {
                sb.Append(text.Substring(currentPos, match.Index - currentPos));
                string f = match.Result(match.Groups[1].Value + match.Groups[2].Value.Replace("\"", "&quot;")) + "\"";
                sb.Append(f);
                currentPos = match.Index + match.Length;
            }

            sb.Append(text.Substring(currentPos));

            Console.Write(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work for the following. Can you help? string text = "<a b = \"a\" c = \"6\" d = \"(Replace( Replace( \"[i]\", \"j\", \"\" ), \"j/\", \"\" ))#k\" />";

Comment: Basically when a bracket exists.

Comment: Nope, it was due to space surrounding the "=" sign of the attribute. I corrected it.

Comment: Thanks, but then can you help me with the space problem? In my test case, a space exists surrounding "=". Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it's ok. Even more, I posted you an answer for your question about Finding in a List.